# is it ok to write Javascript or jQuery code as a PHP file in CodeIgniter views?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have created a JavaScript file as a PHP file in my CodeIgniter views so that I can access some of my PHP dynamic variable in JavaScript.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('loginpage'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {emailId:email1,password:pwd1},
        success: function(result){
```

Is this OK?

Comment: yeah it's ok. Php parse at server side so before sending response it will parse all it's variable to strings and send the js code. Also, put them in <script> tag

Comment: if you okay with javascript then use Angular Js don't use codeigniter it will make your work heard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is perfectly alright , I am using this in a professional project

```
 var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#searchCategory').change(function(){
        var id = $('#searchCategory').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: base_url+"home/getSubCategory",
            data: {id:id},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#sub_category").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is ok.
For Eg:

```
$.ajax
            ({
                type:"POST",
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>staff_activity/date_report",
                data:'year='+nep_year+'&month='+nep_month,
                success:function(msg)
                {

                    $('#result').html(msg);
                },
                beforeSend:function(d)
                {
                    $('#result').html("<center style='color:red;'>Please Wait......</center>");
                }
            });
```